# getting argument exception in concurrent dictionary when sorting and displaying as it is being updated

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency, race-condition, concurrentdictionary

I am getting a hard to reproduce error in the following program in which a number of threads update a concurrent dictionary in parallel and the main thread displays the state of the dictionary in sorted order after fixed time intervals, until all updating threads complete.

```
public void Function(IEnumerable<ICharacterReader> characterReaders, IOutputter outputter)
{
    ConcurrentDictionary<string, int> wordFrequencies = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, int>();
    Thread t = new Thread(() => UpdateWordFrequencies(characterReaders, wordFrequencies));
    bool completed = false;
    var q = from pair in wordFrequencies orderby pair.Value descending, pair.Key select new Tuple<string, int>(pair.Key, pair.Value);
    t.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(0);

    while (!completed)
    {
        completed = t.Join(1);
        outputter.WriteBatch(q);
    }            
}
```

The function is given a list of character streams and an outputter. The function maintains a concurrent dictionary of word frequencies of words read from each of the character streams (in parallel). The words are read in by a new thread, and the main thread outputs the current state of the dictionary (in sorted order) every 1 miliseconds until all the input streams have been read (in practice the outputting will be something like every 10 seconds, but the error only seems to be appearing for very small values). The WriteBatch function just writes to the console:

```
public void WriteBatch(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> batch)
{
    foreach (var tuple in batch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Most executions are fine, but sometimes I get the following error at the foreach statement in the WriteBatch function:

"Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The index is equal to or greater
than the length of the array, or the number of elements in the dictionary is gre
ater than the available space from index to the end of the destination array."

The error does seem to go away if the main thread sleeps for a short while after starting the updating threads and before starting the display loop. It also seems to go away if the orderby clause is removed and the dictionary is not sorted in the linq query. Any explanations?

The `foreach (var tuple in batch)` statement in the WriteBatch function gives the error. The stack trace is as follows:

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The index is equal to or greater
than the length of the array, or the number of elements in the dictionary is gre
ater than the available space from index to the end of the destination array.
    at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary2.System.Collections.Ge
    neric.ICollection>.CopyTo(K
    eyValuePair2[] array, Int32 index)
       at System.Linq.Buffer1..ctor(IEnumerable1 source)
       at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable1.d__0.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator2.MoveNext()
       at MyProject.ConsoleOutputter.WriteBatch(IEnumerable1 batch) in         C:\MyProject\ConsoleOutputter.cs:line 10
       at MyProject.Function(IEnumerable1 characterReaders, IOutputter outputter)

Comment: Which line gives the exception?

Comment: Also, is there a stack trace?  Can you post it?

Comment: My hunch is, as with almost all hard-to-reproduce concurrency problems, you have some sort of race conditions here. I think the problem is that while you're going over the dictionary it is being changed by the other threads. If you want to output the dictionary's status at a point in time you need to get a static snapshot of it at that moment and print *that* out, not the reference you give to your function. Try doing all the work on  `q.ToArray()` instead of on the dictionary itself. I think that might solve it. If it does let me know and I'll post it as an answer, I'm just not totally sure.

Comment: @MichaelDmitryAzarkevich I doubt it.  From the docs on ConcurrentDictionary: "All public and protected members of ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue> are thread-safe and may be used concurrently from multiple threads." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Comment: I have updated with the stack trace. The exception occurs in the foreach statement in the WriteBatch function. Yes it is some kind of race, but I would really like to know why its happening. The idea of taking a snapshot with ToArray() is good, but doesnt that cause a performance overhead and unnecessary copying? What about just synchronizing on the whole concurrent dictionary when displaying?

Comment: First of all, @ChrisShain , they're thread-safe but that only guarantees that while printing a single element it won't change. Between that and the printing of the next element the whole dictionary could be deleted.
Second, SanoritaRm, that is also an option. The point is you need to freeze the dictionary somehow during printing.

Comment: @MichaelDmitryAzarkevich yep, I stand corrected.  Definitely a race condition in the LINQ `Buffer1` class constructor.  That said, doing a `ToArray` is still not sufficient, because that may have the same behavior.  You need to synchronize access while copying the pairs

Comment: @ChrisShain agreed. In short - you need to get mutually exclusive access to the dictionary when printing, either with a mutex or a lock statement.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As others have said, there is a race in the constructor of the internal class `System.Linq.Buffer<T>`, which is called by `OrderBy`.

Here is the offending code snippet:

```
TElement[] array = null;
int num = 0;
if (collection != null)
{
    num = collection.Count;
    if (num > 0)
    {
        array = new TElement[num];
        collection.CopyTo(array, 0);
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown when item(s) are added to the `collection` after the call to `collection.Count` but before the call to `collection.CopyTo`.

---

As a work around, you can make a "snapshot" copy of the dictionary before you sort it.

You can do this by calling `ConcurrentDictionary.ToArray.`
 As this is implemented in the `ConcurrentDictionary` class itself, it is safe.

Using this approach means you don't have to protect the collection with a lock which, as you say, defeats the purpose of using a concurrent collection in the first place.

```
while (!completed)
{
    completed = t.Join(1);

    var q =
      from pair in wordFrequencies.ToArray() // <-- add ToArray here
      orderby pair.Value descending, pair.Key
      select new Tuple<string, int>(pair.Key, pair.Value);

    outputter.WriteBatch(q);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! this clears things up, I was uncomfortable with the idea of taking a full lock on a concurrent collection (I wonder if that is ever a good idea).

Comment: +1, thanks. It seems even `ToList()` has the same race condition, which (ironically) I had tried using to create a snapshot in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

After a discussion with ChrisShain in the comments, the conclusion is that you should get mutually exclusive access to the dictionary before printing it out, either with a `mutex` of a `lock` statement.

Doing it with a lock:

```
public void WriteBatch(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> batch)
{
    lock (myLock) 
    {
        foreach (var tuple in batch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

assuming you allocated a `myLock` object at the class level. See [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx).

Doing it with a mutex:

```
public void WriteBatch(IEnumerable<Tuple<string, int>> batch)
{
    mut.WaitOne();

    foreach (var tuple in batch)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", tuple.Item1, tuple.Item2);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();

    mut.ReleaseMutex();
}
```

Again, assuming you allocated a `Mutex` object at the class level. See [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Michael, Shain. Synchronization seems to be the way to go, but this is not the complete solution right? The lock needs to be taken by each of the updating threads as well - right? But that will kind of defeat the purpose of using concurrent dictionary - the same could be done with unsafe dictionary as we are locking the whole thing anyway. Some how I need full sync between display and updating  group, and fine grained sync (exploiting concurrent dictionary) between all the threads that are updating.

Comment: Thanks guys, Nicholas had the neat idea of using the ToArray() on the concurrent collection itself so we can -safely- take a snapshot as Michael suggested initially.